# замена "z" на "w" и наоборот в с#

Tags: c#

Как заменить "z" на "w" и наоборот? Пробовал все возможные методы с Replace, но никак не получается. Не понимаю как работает Replace.

Я хочу, что бы при вводе строки, в которой есть символы "z" или "w".
Выводилась строка, где эти два символа заменены друг другом.
Примеры:

```
Ввод: zebrowwka. 
Вывод: webrozzka.

Ввод: zzz 121 www. 
Вывод:  www 121 zzz
```

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();

string letter = "z";
string letterw = "w";
string a = "z";
string b = "w";

string result =  str.Replace(letter, letterw).Replace(b, a);
```

Comment: непонятно что ты хочешь получить в результате

Comment: `.Replace` меняет вхождения маленькой строки в большой. Ты сейчас пытаешься заменить в строке `z` все подстроки `w` - которых в ней вообще нет

Comment: Замените z на @, w на z, а @ на w, где @ - символ, отсутствующий в строке

Comment: @MBo а если строка будет содержать все 1111998 символов юникода?

Comment: @andreymal А вы коварный ;-)

Comment: @andreymal ответил

Comment: Низкоуровневый подход: `if (char  in ("w", "z")) newchar = char ^ ("w"^"z");`

Comment: Часто вижу этот баг: встречные `replace` не работают.

Answer (score 2):

```
var tempStr = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}1%^!2@#%^)(5&@#$%^6#@!^7#$8%^";

var result =  str.Replace("z",tempStr)
                    .Replace("w", "z")
                    .Replace(tempStr, "w");
```

tempStr необходим что бы уберечься от ситуации где в строке будет едининичный временный символ который мы используем. Весьма сомневаюсь что такая стремная кобминация спецсимволов и цифр будет часто встречатся в текстах

Что б люди в комментариях не занудствовали вот второй вариант:

```
var str = "zzz 121 www";
var tmp = str.Split('z').Select(x => x.Replace("w", "z")).ToArray();
var rez = String.Join("w", tmp);
```

но я бы не заморачивался и писал бы первым.

Но в общем-то можно сделать значительно оптимальнее чем оба кода но... для чего?

Comment: Каждый раз, когда я вижу или даже сам пишу такую реализацию, злая часть меня очень хочет подставить содержимое tempStr в исходную строку)

Comment: ну статистически маловероятно так что любой внешний тест оно успешно пройдет)

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA, кроме того, в котором будет эта строка :)

Comment: @Grundy что практически невозможно. Но ок, сделал еще один вариант который сработает с абсолютно любой строкой. Но лично я бы делал первым вариантом)

Comment: Ага, тоже про сплит думал. В принципе можно было Join сразу делать, а не отдельной строкой :)

Comment: да слишком громоздко будет. Вообще я уже привык к иному синтаксису `.joined("w")` -- так проще) Но это в другом языке) Там вообще вышло бы `str.split("z").map{ $0.replaced("w","z")}.joined("w")`. А шарп после этого кажется в принципе слишком громоздким

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA, я думал Join есть в Linq, и он там есть - но для другого :-D

Comment: Это самосбывающееся пророчество. Редкая строка, которую нигде найти невозможно, попадает на SO, оттуда в поисковую выдачу и вероятность найти её существенно возрастает. Она уже не редкая.

Comment: Связанная задача: дан текст, предъявить недлинную подстроку, которой нет в тексте. Хочется линейный алгоритм с ответом логарифмической длины.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy только в случае если вопрос сам взлетел, а человек не сделал собственную строку используя этот же алгоритм) По поводу связанной задачи - думаю что никто не запрещает создать новый вопрос и дождаться ответа там :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy теперь все будет ок даже если вопрос взлетит в раздаче :D

Answer (score 2):

У меня сердце кровью обливается, когда я вижу создание множества ненужных промежуточных строк.

Делаем замену за один проход по строке. Используется промежуточный `StringBuilder`.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == 'z')
        sb.Append('w');
    else if (str[i] == 'w')
        sb.Append('z');
    else
        sb.Append(str[i]);
}
var result = sb.ToString();
```

Набор `if-else` можно заменить на паттерн-матчинг:

```
sb.Append(str[i] switch { 'z' => 'w', 'w' => 'z', _ => str[i] });
```

Правда, этот способ работает только в случае замены *одного* символа на другой *один* символ.

P.S. Можно ещё небезопасный код с указателями задействовать, тогда вообще без дополнительной памяти можно обойтись.

Comment: Хорошее оптимальное решение про которое я говорил в конце своего ответа. Только в большинстве случаев в нем нет необходимости и занимает больше строк кода) И тут больше вопрос "а для чего"? Только если для тренировки, наверное. Но с меня плюс за оптимальное решение.

Answer (score -1):

Отвечу как новичок новичку. Встречно два метода `Replace` не отработают. Они будут выполняться друг за другом последовательно. Поэтому для решения задачи в данном случае можно просто сделать так:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();

s = s.Replace('z','x').Replace('w', 'z').Replace('x', 'w');

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Не сработает если в строке изначально есть иксы. Они должны сохраниться, но будут перезаписаны на w.

Comment: попробуй этот код на строке: zzz 121 www.